# Get a phone number which called to my rented number from Voximplant

Tags: voximplant

How can I get a phone number which called to my rented number from Voximplant? I tried GetCall history but can't find the phone number.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following parameter to your request: with_calls=true